# Error Route Not Found on RestAdapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have this route configuration on my router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.resource('posts');
});

export default Router;
```

and inside my routes folder I have this posts.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      return this.store.find('post');
    }
});
```

and inside my model folder I have this ember-data model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr()
});
```

And here's my Adapter

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

However whenever I access the resource(localhost:4200/posts) I receive this error

```
Error while processing route: posts Not Found ember$data$lib$adapters$rest$adapter$$default<.ajaxError@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:60763:35
ember$data$lib$adapters$rest$adapter$$default<.ajax/</hash.error@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:60838:37
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3350:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3462:7
done@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9518:1
.send/callback@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9920:8
```

NOTE:

I've also set up a mock http rest server using this command `ember g http-mock post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Turns out the the mock I needed to create a mock with the same name as my resource that's configured in the router.js

so I created a new http mock using this one

```
ember g http-mock posts
```

in my case, Turns out that the route specified should be the same as the JSON you are retrieving.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change `this.resource('posts')` to `this.route('posts')`. You don't need resources with latest version of ember.

Comment: But how will I add models to my routes then?

Comment: Didn't understand your question. For models you have `model` hook in your route.

Comment: Inside `Router.map` you just tell ember what routes do you have

Comment: I tried using your answer but the error still persists

Comment: Look in browser console, network tab. Do you see any errors there?

Comment: Yes. but the same error persists like the one I posted. an error 404 on localhost:4200/posts but I don't understand why.

Comment: Is your adapter in the right place (app/adapters/application.js)?

Comment: it's inside the app/adapter/application.js

Comment: and I believe it's working properly since I can access localhost:4200/api/posts

Comment: Replace `export default DS.RESTAdapter.reopen` with `export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend`

Comment: What's the difference between extend and reopen?

Comment: Extend creates a new class with some additional/overriden methods. Reopen changes base class. In most cases you need extend.